# Updating only a portion string and keeping rest the same

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a value "0x1FF40001" that I write into a register like this,

```
myserial[0].write(0x807, 0x1FF40001);
```

But now firmware is saying that there are 4 parts in that value I write to the register 807, "1F F4 00 01" and that the second nibble (32bits) which is currently "F4" (Antenna Index) can change by user input and can have values from 0-255 (decimal). Said currently the value is 4.

So I add it to the Win Form to enter the value for Antenna Index this way:

[image]

```
//In Form1.Designer.cs
this.Antenna_index_box.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Antenna_index_box_TextChanged);

//In Form1.cs
private void Antenna_index_box_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uint[] ant_index = Antenna_index_box.Text;
            Ant_indx = ant_index;    //Ant_indx is a global variable so that I may pass it
        }
```

Now, how do I only change a portion of that string before I write it? The user input for Ant_indx is now in a global variable `Ant_indx`.

```
myserial[0].write(0x807, Ant_indx);
```

I want to change only the "F4" in the string 0x1F"F4"0001 and keep the rest as the same.

If the user enters 4, I should program 807 as 0x1F040001

If the user enters 25, I should program 807 as 0x1F1D0001

How do I only change those bits alone?

```
myserial[0].write(0x807, Ant_indx);   // both arguments have to be uint32
```

**EDIT:**
I implemented it this way :

```
     UInt32 special_register_value = 0x1FF00001;
     special_register_value |= (Ant_indx << 16);
     serial[0].write(0x807, special_register_value);
```

Comment: A "nibble" is only 4 bits. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble

Comment: It's my mistake of understanding the firmware. I am only supposed to modify one nibble. Not two. So not change F4, just change 4. The value for that field can change from 0 - F.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change single characters of a string by index, you could hard code other string options, then switch the string when the user enters a number(you would need to pass the index reference to the event). here is a hypothetical situation:

```
    int antennaIndex;
    switch (antennaIndex) {

        case 4: ant_index = "1F040001"; break;
        case 25: ant_index = "1F1D0001" break;
    }

    Ant_Index = ant_index;
    myserial.write(0x807, Convert.ToUInt32(Ant_Index, 16));
```

Either that or you need to iterate through the string contents with a loop and check for the characters you wish to change, then pass the modified contents to a new string and assign the new modified string to the old one. Here is a  [link](https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/csharp/replace-or-remove-char-in-string-by-index.html) for some options you could use. Best of luck!

Comment: Ok. Will this change if both the arguments for `myserial.write(0x807, Ant_Index)` are to be `UInt32`. Turns out, I cannot pass string.